# Dynamic Css Scaling absolute divs inside relative div with Vue js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, scale

I'm working on a Cinema related project for **mobile-browser** with **Vue.js**. I got the seat planning with `position:absolute` inside `position:relative` `div`. Apart from the seat planning, I also want the seating plan to be zoom-able. I managed to make it scalable by setting the `scale` of the parent `div`. However there are couple problems with that.

1. The seats are not horizontally center with the **Screen** since they are `position:absolute`.
2. I want the scaling of the seating plan to be fit to the parent `div`.
3. Also when I Zooming In, the seats on the left are not visible.

Here's my code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seats,
    zoomScale: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    zoom: function (action) {
      if (action == '-') this.zoomScale -= 0.2;
      else if (action == '+') this.zoomScale += 0.2;
      else this.zoomScale = 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.screen {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.seat-plan {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  
  overflow: auto;
}

.zoom-able {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.seat {
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="screen">Screen</div>

  <div class="seat-plan">

    <div
      class="zoom-able"
      :style="{transform: `scale(${zoomScale})`}"
    >
      <button
        class="seat"
        v-for="(seat, index) in seats"
        :key="index"
        :style="{left: `${seat.x}px`,top: `${seat.y}px`}"
       >
        {{ index }}
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>{{ zoomScale }}</div>
  <div class="zoom-buttons">
    <button @click="zoom('-')">-</button>
    <button @click="zoom('default')">default</button>
    <button @click="zoom('+')">+</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
var seats = [{"x":78,"y":0,},{"x":104,"y":0,},{"x":130,"y":0,},{"x":156,"y":0,},{"x":182,"y":0,},{"x":208,"y":0,},{"x":234,"y":0,},{"x":286,"y":0,},{"x":312,"y":0,},{"x":338,"y":0,},{"x":364,"y":0,},{"x":390,"y":0,},{"x":416,"y":0,},{"x":52,"y":34,},{"x":78,"y":34,},{"x":104,"y":34,},{"x":130,"y":34,},{"x":156,"y":34,},{"x":182,"y":34,},{"x":208,"y":34,},{"x":234,"y":34,},{"x":286,"y":34,},{"x":312,"y":34,},{"x":338,"y":34,},{"x":364,"y":34,},{"x":390,"y":34,},{"x":416,"y":34,},{"x":442,"y":34,},{"x":52,"y":68,},{"x":78,"y":68,},{"x":104,"y":68,},{"x":130,"y":68,},{"x":156,"y":68,},{"x":182,"y":68,},{"x":208,"y":68,},{"x":234,"y":68,},{"x":286,"y":68,},{"x":312,"y":68,},{"x":338,"y":68,},{"x":364,"y":68,},{"x":390,"y":68,},{"x":416,"y":68,},{"x":442,"y":68,},{"x":52,"y":102,},{"x":78,"y":102,},{"x":104,"y":102,},{"x":130,"y":102,},{"x":156,"y":102,},{"x":182,"y":102,},{"x":208,"y":102,},{"x":234,"y":102,},{"x":286,"y":102,},{"x":312,"y":102,},{"x":338,"y":102,},{"x":364,"y":102,},{"x":390,"y":102,},{"x":416,"y":102,},{"x":442,"y":102,},{"x":52,"y":136,},{"x":78,"y":136,},{"x":104,"y":136,},{"x":130,"y":136,},{"x":156,"y":136,},{"x":182,"y":136,},{"x":208,"y":136,},{"x":234,"y":136,},{"x":286,"y":136,},{"x":312,"y":136,},{"x":338,"y":136,},{"x":364,"y":136,},{"x":390,"y":136,},{"x":416,"y":136,},{"x":442,"y":136,},{"x":78,"y":170,},{"x":104,"y":170,},{"x":130,"y":170,},{"x":156,"y":170,},{"x":182,"y":170,},{"x":208,"y":170,},{"x":234,"y":170,},{"x":286,"y":170,},{"x":312,"y":170,},{"x":338,"y":170,},{"x":364,"y":170,},{"x":390,"y":170,},{"x":416,"y":170,}]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've been solving the wrong problem. Finally I found my solution from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481026/css-transform-scale-scrolling-issue/30481261).

The problem was from the css `transform-origin` which is causing the positioning of the buttons when `transform: scale()`. So the solution is wrapping the buttons with a div and set `transform-origin: 0 0;`, which will reset the origin of the div wrapping the buttons when scaling.